# ELF: why struct variable is put into section with 32 bytes aligned in 64 bits system

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, elf

The code:

```
// test.c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct cgi
{
        const char *cgi_name;
        void *data;
        uint32_t flags;
} cgi_t;

static cgi_t a, b, c;
```

compile it:

```
$ cc -c test.c
```

readelf

```
$ readelf -a test.o

     5: 0000000000000000    24 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 a
     6: 0000000000000020    24 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 b
     7: 0000000000000040    24 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 c
```

so strange, these 3 variable are placed to address aligned to 0x20. this behavior make following code failed:

```
extern cgi_t __start_cgicalls, __stop_cgicalls;

cgi_t * lookup_cgi(const char *name) {
    cgi_t *cgi_entry;
    for (cgi_entry = &__start_cgicalls;
        cgi_entry < &__stop_cgicalls; cgi_entry++) {
        if (!strcmp(name, cgi_entry->cgi_name))
            return cgi_entry;
    }   
    return NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

I put registered cgi entry to a cgi section, and look them, because they are place at wrong offset, so I look them up with program crashed.

==============

I fix it by force struct align to 16 bytes. I found a material says that,

> when a struct is bigger than 16bytes, the variable will be algined to
>   16 bytes

```
typedef int (* cgicb_t)(struct http_req *req, struct http_res *res);

/* note: because we look up cgi entry based on array align (8 bytes in 64bits system)
    but the variable may be put in section with different align (big struct is aligned to 16 bytes)
    so, here we force the align to 16 bytes !!!
 */
typedef struct cgi 
{
    const char *cgi_name;
    cgicb_t fn; 
    uint32_t flags;
} __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) cgi_t;

#define REGISTER_CGI(name, cb, flag) \
    static cgi_t __cgicall##cb \
        __attribute__((__section__("cgicalls"))) __attribute__((used)) \
        = { \
            .cgi_name = name, \
            .fn = cb, \
            .flags = flag, \
        } 

#define REG_CGI(cb) REGISTER_CGI(CGI_PATH #cb, cb, CGI_FLAG_PERM)
```

Comment: The compiler is generally free to align objects more generously if it thinks it will be good for performance (e.g. this way each object lives within a single cache line).  Your code should not make assumptions about how this happens.  If you want an array of objects, make it an array instead of three separate objects.

Comment: An array uses the same alignment as its elements, except that a local or global array variable of length at least 16 bytes or a C99 variable-length array variable always has alignment of at least 16 bytes。

Comment: "I fix it by ..." you didn't fix *anything*. You created a temporary hack that happens to work for your current platform. Your solution may break with the next compiler release, with different flags, on a different architecture, etc. etc.

Comment: but linux kernel also use same hack to support init calls. see: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/init.h#L200 @EmployedRussian

Answer (score 2):

> so strange, these 3 variable are placed to address aligned to 0x20

Your question is very confusing, because it has *nothing* to do with any sections.

Your question appears to be: "why are `a`, `b` and `c` spaced 32 bytes apart when `sizeof(cgi_t) == 24`?".

Your assumption that `a`, `b` and `c` follow each other in the `.bss` section is *invalid*. Compiler could place them in `b`, `a`, `c` or any other order, or it could put some other data between them.

To make the order and placement well-defined, you *must* declare an *array* of them: `static cgi_t cgicalls[3];`.

Comment: The use case is that these cgi entries are registered to cgicalls section dynamically.